# When Shutdown Hooks Break Bad

Tags: java, runtime, shutdown

If I add a *shutdown hook* to my Java program's runtime like so:

```
public class MyShutdownHook implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Stuff I want executed anytime
        // the program, Java, or the OS exits normally,
        // crashes, or terminates unexpectedly for any reason.
    }
}

// The in another method...
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new MyShutdownHook());
```

...then are there *ever* any situations where that `run()` method won't execute when the program/Java/OS exits normally, crashes or terminates unexpectedly? If so, what situations would be able to by-pass `Runtime`'s shutdown hook, and why?

Comment: Never discount the possibility of a nuclear attack on your computer.

Comment: are you asking for more information beyond the javadoc's description of how this work?

Comment: @Mark Peters: : ) funny joke...  But don't forget that *SIGKILL*  pretty much *is* an atomic waepon ; )  On both Linux and OS X (two name only two Un*x-like commonly used by developers) a *kill -9* is *guaranteed* to instantly kill the process and to release its resources, no question asked.  No *ShutDownHook*.  No nothing.  Now I agree: a Java process won't see any difference between a *kill -9* and a nuclear attack ; )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If the process is killed, a shutdown hook will not be executed.
- If the process crashes, a shutdown hook will not be executed.
- If you have a Windows service and the shutdown hook takes to long to execute, it will be terminated.

Comment: Keep in mind, that is only killed by SIGKILL, SIGTERM and similar still runs the shutdown hook

Comment: If the process is sent a SIGTERM signal (regular "kill" command in UNIX) then the shutdown hook will run.  It will only fail to run if sent SIGKILL (kill -9).

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, if I `kill -11 <pid>` the Java process it won't run the shutdown hook there either.  Although I guess you might say that falls under the "crashes" bullet.

Answer (score 4):

If you pull the plug out the back of your computer then the shut-down hook won't run.  Other situations include:

- The process being killed on a POSIX OS with SIGKILL (-9).
- Similarly if you elect to terminate an "unresponsive" process under Windows the shut-down hook may not complete.

Answer (score 0):

They only run if the process "shuts down normally."  If the process is killed forcefully from the OS or if it's crashing due to resource issues (e.g., out of memory), shutdown hooks won't be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `Runtime.getRuntime().halt()` the JVM or when the OS kills the process without allowing it to run any cleanup, also when you have eclipse terminate the program (when running it under eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Any time the JVM can exit gracefully, the shutdown hook is run. It is not run if:

- The JVM crashes. (Depending on how/when it crashes, the hook *may* still run, but no guarantees are made)
- The JVM gets SIGKILL or similar, and is immediately stopped by the OS