# Is Shutdownhook guaranteed to be execute if JVM crashes

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Shutdown Hooks Break Bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171646/when-shutdown-hooks-break-bad)

I want to know if shutdownhook is guaranteed to execute in the scenario if JVM crashes.

Comment: It looks like didn't even read the javadoc…

Comment: Well, if you shut down the machine for example, it is guaranteed that nothing is happening anymore. Conclusion: The JVM can not control the world outside the JVM.

Comment: Do you mean a JVM Crash? No.  If you mean a shutdown after an Exception, then they should run.  Most of the time when people talk about a JVM Crash they means their program threw an Exception or an Error.

Answer (score 11):

Nope. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. **If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

shutdownhook however creates a thread for whatever tasks needed to be done before JVM starts shutdown and if the machine itself gets shutdown the thread created by the shutdownhook
will never get the CPU cycles for there execution and i think here the shutdownhook will not get executed...

Comment: You asked what happens if the JVM crashes, not what happens if the computer is forcibly shutdown. In the latter case, I think it is intuitively obvious that nothing (not even shutdown hooks) will be executed after power is removed.

Comment: hey thanks !! i was just working on the possible scenarios of JVM getting crashed..